# Want to integrate SVN with the apacheds user's

Tags: centos, svn, openldap

Currently i have SVN installed in the centos server with which currently authenticating with ssh user's from the same server. 
I have installed ApacheDS in centos intending to authenticate with apacheds user's. Can any one please provide some hints to do so.
Earlier we used to have Windows Active directory setup, In Centos machine we used to install Centrifydc express to link centos machine with ADS So SVN used to authenticate with ADS User's.

Now i'm moved to Apacheds, How to achieve SVN installed in Centos will get autheticated with Apacheds User's

Answer (score 0):

ApacheDS is LDAP after all, you can use the same technique as used in pure Apache for pure LDAP

- https://www.open.collab.net/support/media/pdfs/SVN/Subversion%20with%20Apache%20and%20LDAP.pdf
- https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/svn+ldap
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn+ldap